# Token is not transferred as hidden field

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I've been desperate for hours on that token. I can create it, it is written in the email link and in the query string - but it is not transferred to the hidden field of the form and therefore does not reach the controller.

```
//send email
var callbackUrl = Url.Action(controller: "Account", action: "ResetPassword", values: new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Scheme);

await this._emailSender.SendEmailAsync(
     email: user.Email,
     username: user.UserName,
     subject: "Reset Password",
     message: callbackUrl);
```

Resetpassword.cshtml

```
@model ViewModel.ResetPasswordViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Reset password";
}

<h2>@ViewData["Title"].</h2>

<form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="ResetPassword" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <h4>Reset your password.</h4>
    <hr />
    <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
    <input asp-for="Code" type="hidden" />
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Email" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Password" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="ConfirmPassword" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input asp-for="ConfirmPassword" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="ConfirmPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Reset" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial"); }
}
```

Example-link:
http://localhost:55555/Account/ResetPassword?userId=d98b3d27-5769-49c9-9abc-b6532d87d5ea&code=CfDJ8Bf0Swqf1I9At8y5jfYr%252bjZauqH5iIcDJefAiuW5b4bcE3e7VuZp7VSu9Cb%252bAqa61CBnC1NlSxRCyzwLyOKYfvXUGQHfroXa7bIObn4hjAowdVHg5ab%252blBckuKV50XgMUXRRPM4deNVm18b6XtVMf8c0QSFj4fNLxT15OP%252fcN6LxNuUf%252bhOQy8lTIV1AxOwsk%252bY58wI9BoGFcqrJDHtkuvdYP6mO%252fTaHy4uMq49Lqc%252b2p7cqDTiHBK0%252bCLRQumBiEw%253d%253d

Code is there - but  remains empty.

And so my model does contains null in Code and null in _RequestVerificationToken

Here my ResetPasswordViewModel:

```
public class ResetPasswordViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string _RequestVerificationToken { get; set; }

}
```

I tried different examples and haven't changed them, but the tokens just don't work for me.

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> ResetPassword(ResetPasswordViewModel model)
{

    var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
    var identityResult = await _userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user, model.Code, model.Password);
    //var identityResult = await _userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user, model._RequestVerificationToken, model.Password);

    if (!identityResult.Succeeded)
    {
        return View("Error");
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");  //ToDo new View

        //var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
        //if (user == null)
        //    throw new InvalidOperationException();

        //if (model.Password != model.ConfirmPassword)
        //{
        //    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Passwords do not match");
        //    return View();
        //}

        //var resetPasswordResult = await _userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user, model.Code, model.Password);
        //if (!resetPasswordResult.Succeeded)
        //{
        //    foreach (var error in resetPasswordResult.Errors)
        //        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
        //    return View();
        //}

        //return Content("Password updated");
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the signature of the controller method ResetPassword?

Comment: Hi, 

sorry I did not see your comment until now.

Controller is short at the moment (because it always went into error). I extend it above. Thanks!

Comment: Hope someone has an answer...

Comment: You've posted the ResetPassword POST method. The problem is likely in your ResetPassword GET method. Please add that method to your code example.

Comment: Oh yes that was the problem :( only the get method was missing. Thanks!